# Regarding building Linux kernel image for x86

Tags: linux-kernel

I need to compile Linux kernel for x86 Architecture and replace my current Debian kernel.

I compiled the kernel as follows

```
make-kpkg kernel_image kernel_headers
```

I believe it is building Debian kernel, but how should I replace the kernel image of my running kernel? Please advise also, please let me know if I'm following wrong steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your source-code

Do the following stuff.

1) `make menuconfig`

this will read your config-x.x.x file from /boot folder.

if you want enable then enable something ,enable it.

2)`save and quit menuconfig`.

3)`make bzImage`

---> this will bild bzImage.

4)`make modules`

---> this will build modules

5)`sudo make modules_install`

--> this will install your modules in `/lib/modules/linux-x.x.x`

6)`sudo make install`

this will install bzImage

7)`sudo reboot`

`How i can check ?`

Once u reboot check for your kernel version

$ `uname –a`

this will show recent kernel version which you have built.

Comment: you made the job so simple for me, thanks as always!

Comment: These moderators have banned me from asking questions because they think I ask low quality questions. With intelligence comes ego, this proves it. These intelligent people who use this site for their resumes will never understand the meaning of a stupid question. Anyways, Vinay do you have a blog or another contact address.

Comment: you can contact me @ vinayhunachyal@gmail.com. Im planning to write a blog due to time constraint and some other hobbies  im not able to do it. Well if i write ill let you know ,

Answer (score 1):

some distros have built in tools to do that, I don't know if debian has that, because I use fedora linux, but the manual way is:

1) copy the kernel image from the output folder to your boot folder.

2) check if you need to rebuild initramfs.

3) update your grub entries to point to the new kernel image

4) reboot

Comment: before executing make-kpkg I copied the configuration file from /boot/ to the linux .config. Is that a correct way to get the config of current os?

Comment: Yes, that is the best way to do it.