# Kernel configuration error during make menuconfig

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile, config

HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
/tmp/ccsuEio0.o: In function `parse_dep_file':
fixdep.c:(.text+0x2f2): undefined reference to`__ctype_b'
fixdep.c:(.text+0x5b4): undefined reference to `__stdout'
fixdep.c:(.text+0x5ea): undefined reference to`__fputc_unlocked'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2

i get this error when i try to configure linux 3.11 kernel. currently i using linux 3.13.0.34 kernel, i was getting make menuconfig well but dont know what i did,
now its showing the above error,

i have installed build-essentials.

someone help me on this.

Comment: Which architecture(ARM, X86) are you trying to build for ?  How did you obtain the default config ?

Comment: X86 and i dont have a default .config file there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847061/regarding-building-linux-kernel-image-for-x86/24861452#24861452   try this

Comment: linux-libc-dev uses some old linux-headers which i accidently removed in an autoremove command. Please help me to get back those headers. I got some info here..http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders

Answer (score 0):

Firstly WIthout .config file you cannot build you kernel source (either you need to manually enalbe or disable the modules or use the config of the same machine to build)

1. Go to /boot
2. You will find the default configuration file like **config-3.2.03-generic** suitable for your machine
3. Copy that config file to your kernel source folder as **.config**
4. then **make menuconfig**, save and exit
5. **make** to build the kernel source, hope you will not that error if you follow these steps

Comment: sir i tried what you said but still i get the same error at make menuconfig

Comment: can you share the .config file

Comment: sir how can i share from her im new to this. sir can i add that .config file to an older kernel source, because i used it to compile a 3.11 kernel whereas the .config file i took was for 3.13

Comment: 1. you can copy that file to any online file sharing website,           2. Yes you can use the same config file from 3.13 to build for 3.11

Comment: I tried to build on my PC and its building as expected, i guess there is some prerequisite that is missing on your PC, find all the prerequisites required to build kernel and follow the same orocedure once again

Comment: sir i installed all dependencies using build-dep and build-essentials, yet i get the same erro.

Comment: linux-libc-dev uses some old linux-headers which i accidently removed in an autoremove command. Please help me to get back those headers. I got some info here..kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders